# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'OneSignal' of undefined

Tags: ionic-framework, onesignal

I am tried to use push notification . so i am using onesignal.
  while using this i got this error

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property      'OneSignal' of
>   undefined"

Code:

```
   .run(function($ionicPlatform) {
       $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
         // Enable to debug issues.
         // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

         var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
           console.log('didReceiveRemoteNotificationCallBack: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
         };

         window.plugins.OneSignal.init("AIzaSyCkgXtEUurHrM5rYUmstQmL7s8HkA6OTpA", {googleProjectNumber: "583817643699"}, notificationOpenedCallback);
         // Show an alert box if a notification comes in when the user is in your app.
         window.plugins.OneSignal.enableInAppAlertNotification(true);
       });
     })
```

plese help me to find good solutions

Comment: Check for device ready. After device ready event is called only then you can use any plugin.

Answer (score 1):

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
               $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
                 // Enable to debug issues.
                 // window.plugins.OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});

                 document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
                    function onDeviceReady() {
                    if(window.plugin != undefined){
                    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
                      alert("Notification opened:\n" + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
                      console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
                    };

                    // TODO: Update with your OneSignal AppId and googleProjectNumber before running.
                    window.plugins.OneSignal
                      .startInit("AIzaSyCkgXtEUurHrM5rYUmstQmL7s8HkA6OTpA", "583817643699")
                      .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
                      .endInit();
                  });
                 }}
               });
             })
```

Maybe because , window.plugin is undefined . try using it in deviceready event function . Hopes it will help you (y)

Comment: may i get any demo video or tutorial link for using onesignal

Comment: Have you gone through this https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/phonegap-sdk .It covers ervery aspect of it .. (y)

Comment: thanks now error is cleared . but in onesignal  still   "Users who can receive push notifications: 0"  is showing after i run in mobile

Comment: and i give alert after if condition of window.plugin is not working

Comment: can you show me your exact error ?  uplaod a image if you can :)

Comment: i am not  getting any error but after run in moblie the onesignal user is not increased still in '0'.

Comment: see this is i got from onesignal  'Users who can receive push notifications: 0'......after run in my mobile also its not increase receive push notifications

Comment: hmm .. I think that's mean no one is subscribed  to it yet . have to check about it :(

Comment: Hey i have just updated the answer , can You check if it works for you ? let me know

Comment: first i want to know how other people subscribe to it